# Itext8 TextMarginFinder strange output coordinates

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

FOA: I'm using recent IText8 core apis, which are very similar to 7 version AFAICS.
As per [documentation](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/java/7.0.0/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/canvas/parser/listener/TextMarginFinder.html) the class TextMarginFinder should help me to find, between all textboxes in my pdf, the maximum and minimum y coordinates, which in a second operation I'd use to crop\clip the unused upper and lower area of the pdf.

[This](https://easyupload.io/bjgyez) is the file I'm using.

This is my code attempt:

```
private static final String pdfTestFile="./ExtractedPage6test.pdf"; 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfTestFile));
        PdfDocumentContentParser contentParser = new PdfDocumentContentParser(pdf);
        TextMarginFinder strategy = contentParser.processContent(1, new TextMarginFinder());//LocationTextExtractionStrategy

        System.out.println("getTop->" +strategy.getTextRectangle().getTop());
        System.out.println("getBottom->" +strategy.getTextRectangle().getBottom());
        System.out.println("getHeight->" +strategy.getTextRectangle().getHeight());
        System.out.println("getX->" +strategy.getTextRectangle().getX());
        System.out.println("getY->" +strategy.getTextRectangle().getY());

        System.out.println("====================");
        System.out.println("getTextRectangle->" +strategy.getTextRectangle());

        System.out.println("toPointsArray->" +     Arrays.stream(strategy.getTextRectangle().toPointsArray()).toList());
 
        //new ExtractTextDimensions().testBeforeAkhilNagaSai(pdfTestFile);
//        new ExtractTextPlusY().testExtractTextPlusYFromTest(pdfTestFile);
    }
```

As you can see there are also some other commented attempt from mkl's classes I've found in other threads here, same strange coordinates as result.

This is the output:

```
getTop->1640.5029

getBottom->764.5649

getHeight->875.93805

getX->86.254974

getY->764.5649

====================

getTextRectangle->Rectangle: 431.03903x875.93805

toPointsArray->[Point: [x=86.255,y=764.565], Point: [x=517.294,y=764.565], Point: [x=517.294,y=1,640.503], Point: [x=86.255,y=1,640.503]]
```

Now, I'm quite confused since the A4 format is 595 x 842 pixels. The coordinates given from the snippet are far beyond those limits.
Also, the resulting bounding box rectangle should be identifiable with only 2 points but resulting PointArray has 4.

Comment: Yes, _the A4 format is 595 x 842_ user space units (not _pixels_,), at least approximately, but this rectangle can be located anywhere on the plane. _Often_ the lower left of that rectangle is at the origin (0,0) but in general it can be anywhere. Unfortunately the link for the file you're using shows "The transfer you requested has been deleted." Thus, I cannot check where the page rectangle is located in your case. Furthermore, there may be off-page text included in the calculation.

Comment: mmm very interesting. Sorry for the short tolerance of the host site, didn't expected to be so limited, I've updated file link with another host, very annoying.
This page has ben extracted from a multipage, also this is the result of a "flattening" I've done before.
Isn't there a way to estabilish what textboxes are in the "visible area"? thanks mkl!
Otherwise, another strategy, since I could chose the wrong attempt to solve my issue.
At least, all the pdfs I need to "trim/clip" has same caracteristics of the one I've uploaded, so in case of solving, I'm not in need to generalize too much.

Comment: Ok, the media box is positioned as usual, so the issue appears to be due to off-page content. Indeed, there are lots of nested form XObjects, some drawn with quite some offsets, some having bounding boxes way off-page, ... It is at least plausible that some off-page content will be found.

Comment: *"Isn't there a way to estabilish what textboxes are in the "visible area"?"* - You can wrap the `TextMarginFinder` in a `FilteredEventListener` with `IEventFilter`s that only accept content inside the media box page area.

Comment: I understood, conceptually, since with so many 404's on documentations is very hard to figure out how to do things, but if I compare the countries textboxes, they have crazy coords. So those would be excluded even if they're visible.
Also, If I open the pdf with an editor like FoxPdf, if I try to get the same textboxes, the coordinates are clearly between the A4 limits.

Comment: I've put my ide in debug mode with visibility of inner strategy field locations visible, so I can see each textboxes coords, because these informations are in private class attributes by design...

Comment: *"so many 404's on documentations"* - currently the iText knowledgebase is moving to a different platform. As they didn't have a permalink concept before, this likely will break some links there...

Comment: Surely even if available won't explain those strange coords for textfields in my pdf...